# Python Using DataFrame to save state of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, state, pickle

What´s the best way to save a for loop count variable state in order to run the same script in different days?

I´m trying to loop over a large dataframe in different days and I want to keep track of the row so I don´t start the loop from the beginning everytime but from the row where I´ve stopped the previous time.

I´ve seen people recommend using Pickle to save state, however I tried that and couldn´t find a way to make it work beacuse I would have to load the count variable on the first time when there would be no variable to load, so is there a way to do it that doesn´t involve Pickle?

Comment: You could have a simple counter `c` in your code, and write the value of `c` to a plain text file. The next day you could open the file with `pd.read_csv()` and use the keyword-argument `skiprows=c`.

Comment: if you use `for`-loop then you could have to use `range(start_value, len(df))` instead of `range(len(df))`, And on first time you could set `start_value = 0` as default value if you don't  have value in file or pickle.

Comment: It is not clear why you "would have to load the count variable on the first time when there would be no variable to load", as you can for example test if the pickle dump file exists.